# Tabla de frecuencias en pandas incorrecta

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Estoy tratando de crear una tabla de frecuencias con pandas pero no obtengo los datos correctos.
Genero los datos con las siguientes líneas:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(29)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50,100,size=(113, 1)), columns=list(['dato']))
```

Uso una semilla para que los datos sean siempre los mismos para todos los que hagan la prueba (creo).

```
bins = pd.interval_range(start=data['dato'].min(), end=data['dato'].max()+1, freq=5)
```

Si no sumo uno al valor máximo del rango, no se crean correctamente.

Ahora creo mi *dataframe*,

```
datos = data.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, sort=False, bins=bins)
```

Y al calcular la *frecuencia absoluta* y la *frecuencia absoluta acumulada* aparece el error.

```py
datos = data.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, sort=False, bins=bins)
datos['FAA'] = datos.cumsum()
datos.columns = ['FA', 'FAA']
```

Esta es la tabla que se produce

```
           FA  FAA
(50, 55]   13   13
(55, 60]    3   16
(60, 65]   16   32
(65, 70]   15   47
(70, 75]   13   60
(75, 80]   11   71
(80, 85]   13   84
(85, 90]   11   95
(90, 95]   10  105
(95, 100]   6  111
```

Si genero 113 datos, **¿por qué solo aparecen 111 datos en la tabla de frecuencias? ¿Cómo se corrige este error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tus intervalos son cerrados a la derecha y **abiertos a la izquierda**, tus dos intervalos extremos equivalen por tanto a:

- **`(50, 55]`**  -> `50 < dato <= 55`
- **`(95, 100]`** ->  `95 < dato <= 100`

Por otro lado `numpy.random.randint(low, high, ...)` genera enteros aleatorios en el rango `low` **incluido** hasta `high` **excluido**. Por lo tanto, el 50 se incluye dentro de los posibles valores generados, pero el 100 no.

El problema por tanto es que hay dos valores de `data.dato` que no entran en ningún intervalo:

> ```
> >>> data[data.dato <= 50]
>     dato
> 20    50
> 57    50
> ```

es decir, hay 15 datos menores o iguales que 55, no 13:

> ```
> >>> data[data.dato <= 55].count()
> dato    15
> dtype: int64
> ```

Por lo tanto, si cierras tus intervalos a la izquierda todos los datos caen en uno:

```
bins = pd.interval_range(
    start=data['dato'].min(),
    end=data['dato'].max()+1,
    freq=5, 
    closed="left"
    )
```

> ```
> >>> datos
>
>            FA  FAA
> [50, 55)   14   14
> [55, 60)    4   18
> [60, 65)   14   32
> [65, 70)   10   42
> [70, 75)   19   61
> [75, 80)   10   71
> [80, 85)   13   84
> [85, 90)   10   94
> [90, 95)   12  106
> [95, 100)   7  113
> ```

Obviamente también cerrando a la derecha pero empezando en el valor mínimo menos uno:

```
start=data['dato'].min() - 1
```

Comment: Me queda clarísimo, muchas gracias. Hice este mismo ejercicio en R y ahí cerré los intervalos a la izquierda. Gracias.